# Android jni javah

Tags: android, jni, c++

Пытаюсь создать h-файл для android через javah. Класс com.example.test.MainActivity. Как правильно использовать javah? Директория должна быть bin/classes или src? Где то читал что может использоваться не тот javah в зависимости от путей в патч(хз какой не тот).

Comment: Пробую так. Не получается
C:\Documents and Settings\mmv\workspace\ru\bin\classes>javah -classpath .D:\Andr
oid\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android-17\andro
id.jar;. -jni ru.ru.ru.MainActivity
Error: cannot access android.app.Activity
  class file for android.app.Activity not found

Comment: Дело было в точке после класспатч xD

Answer (score 1):

- Главной особенностью Java кода, является **native** легко забыть его ;)
- Важным нюансом применения писать входной файл для javah БЕЗ расширения *.class или* .java

Накидал простой пример и как применить. Если что-то у Вас не работает приводите пример

```
/*
 * To header generation:
 * c:>\ javah -d .\include\ NativeMethods
 */

public class NativeMethods {

    native static void superMethod1();

    native static double superMethod2(int[] ints);
}
```